# L2TP/IPsec internet access problem

Tags: internet, 20.04, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

When I try to connect to a VPN (L2TP/IPsec) and don't check the option "use this connection only for resources on its network" i'm not being able to access the Internet, if i use this option i'm not being able to access remote resources

```
When i check "use this connection only for resources on its network"
route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
10.227.89.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ppp0
138.000.000.00  192.168.31.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.31.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlo1

When i don't check "use this connection only for resources on its network"
route -n
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
10.227.89.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ppp0
138.00.000.00   192.168.31.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.31.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlo1

When i don't use vpn 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.31.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.31.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

I find similar bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1598665 , but i can't find solution.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

With a netmask of `255.255.255.255`, when doing split tunneling VPN like you are attempting, it currently only knows how to route to the single host `138.##.###.##` on the remote network. To access other hosts on the same subnet, the netmask would typically be something like `255.255.255.0`, `255.255.0.0`, etc.

I have no idea of the remote network topology or how the VPN server was configured for IPCP queries which result in the netmask of `255.255.255.255`, but on the client side as a workaround, you could manually add a route to the remote subnet you want to reach with something like:

For a netmask of `255.255.255.0` :

```
sudo ip route add 138.##.###.0/24 dev ppp0
```

or if you want a netmask of `255.255.0.0` :

```
sudo ip route add 138.##.0.0/16 dev ppp0
```

note: replace the `#`s with the real IP address octets.

If the above subnets examples are incorrect, add routes to the actual subnet(s) you want to reach on the remote network.

If split tunneling VPN routing is working fine for Windows, perhaps DHCP option 121 or 249 are used. I'm not sure which DHCP client you are using or even if it supports 121 or 249.

Comment: Actually the issue is that both the local and remote networks use the same 192.168.31.0/24 private IP address subnets. You can try configuring your local router to use a different subnet to the remote.